# "def" bringing the wrong answer

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I made a class with some functions:
But when I instantiate the values the answer is bringing me `'alimentos'`, but that's wrong it should be `'portugues'` .

I have two dictionaries and this class:

```
professores_x = {
    'alimentos': [{"prof_id":"xx_alimento_1", "prof_disc":"alimentos"},
                  {"prof_id":"xx_alimento_2", "prof_disc":"alimentos"}],
    'português': [{"prof_id":"xx_port_1", "prof_disc":"português"},
                  {"prof_id":"xx_port_2", "prof_disc":"português"}]}

courses_x = {'alimentos': [{"course_name":"padeiro_confeiteiro"},
                           {"course_name":"padeiro_confeiteiro"}]}


# trying refactoring

class Disciplinas_cursos_1:
    "Define the disciplinas and professors"

    def __init__(self,cursos_,professores_):
        self.cursos_ = cursos_
        self.professores_ = professores_
        for self.p in self.cursos_.keys():
            if self.p == 'alimentos': self.alimentos()
            elif self.p == 'português': self.portugues()

    def alimentos(self):
        profiel_prof_disc = self.professores_[self.p][::]
        prof_disc_al = self.p
        discipl_alimentos = [self.p,[x['prof_id'] for x in profiel_prof_disc
                                                   if x['prof_disc'] == prof_disc_al]]
        return discipl_alimentos

    def portugues(self):
        print("Now its portuguese turn")
        profiel_prof_disc = self.professores_[self.p][::]
        prof_disc_port = self.p
        print(f"see I'm printing {prof_disc_port}. It's that the same of portuguese? If' not it's wrong")
        discipl_port =[self.p,[x['prof_id'] for x in profiel_prof_disc if x['prof_disc'] ==prof_disc_port]]
        print(f"see I'm printing {prof_disc_port} and {discipl_port}")
        return discipl_port


# ok!! Now I do the instance:
disc_a = Disciplinas_cursos_1(courses_x, professores_x)
disc_a.alimentos()
```

**Output**

```
['alimentos', ['xx_alimento_1', 'xx_alimento_2']]
```

Nice, that is what I want but when I try the second function it's bring me `'alimentos'`
but I need `'portugues'` and not `'alimentos'`.

```
disc_a.portugues()
```

**Output**

```
Now its portuguese turn
see I'm printing alimentos. It's that the same of portuguese? If' not it's wrong
see I'm printing alimentos and ['alimentos', ['xx_alimento_1', 'xx_alimento_2']]
```

Comment: Ideally, when asking a question, try to focus on the specific technical problem underlying the unwanted behavior -- the work of isolating what went wrong is something you should do before asking, so that when you ask you can build a [mre] that focuses narrowly on the specific technical problem the question is about. Doing that helps questions and their answers be useful to other people, since the underlying technical problem is something that can come up in programs built for a completely different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with `self.p`. In `__init__`, you're setting that value with your loop, and when you call `self.alimentos()` or `self.portugues()` in the body of the loop it will make sense since the `self.p` value will correspond to the method being called.

But if you call `disc_a.portugues()` from outside of `__init__`, you're going to get the last value `self.p` had after the loop, which may not match up at all with the method you're calling. That's why you're getting invalid output, it's using an inappropriate `self.p` key.

I don't have a firm understanding of what you're intending to do in your methods, so I don't really have a recommended fix. But in general, I'd suggest you think more carefully about which values you're passing to which parts of your code as attributes and as arguments. `self.p` should probably not exist as an attribute. Maybe it should be an argument to the methods? Maybe you need different attributes to sort your data into separate containers, rather than repeatedly looping over it all. You may need to redesign your class to have its data make more sense the way you need to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand.